# PyCharm 2022.1.2 does not hit the debug breakpoint with Django

Tags: python, django, debugging, pycharm, breakpoints

I can't get Python debugger to work on PyCharm 2022.1.2 with Django 4.
When I set the breakpoint inside the view function and then call this view in the browser, nothing happens when started in debug mode...

[breakpoint_selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arx8d.png)

However breakpoint is hit when I set it for import.

[breakpoint_hit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFeHy.png)

I have 2 configurations, one for Python and one for Django Server, both don't work.

[config1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eSQY.png)
[config2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbBfo.png)

Went through numerous JetBrains tickets with people reporting similar problem but didn't find the solution there. Also tried creating second run configuration, for Python instead Django Server, but this also didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by deleting the *.idea* directory from top-level django project dir. Not sure what were the mechanics behind it, but it worked and now breakpoints work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem is already old, but I just encountered a similar case, so I'll tell you about it.

The thing is, the PyCharm debugger uses the `sys.settrace` function to set its own tracing function, so if you have a process that has already captured this API, the debugger does not stop at breakpoints during program execution.

The well-known case is the pytest-coverage module, but I came across another one.

I enabled the `django-debug-toolbar-line-profiling` module, which similarly captured `sys.settrace` and displaced the debugger.

So, if your debugger stopped working somewhere, think about which modules might be setting their own tracing function.